# Is there a default setting to save ArcGIS 10.3.1 .mxd to 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-10.3, save

Does anyone know if there is a setting in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 where we can permanently set the save function to version 10.1? I know that there is **Save a Copy** function, but I don’t want to create duplicate mxds for different versions. I have read through this [site](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/saving-a-map.htm) but it seems to just talk about the **Save a Copy** function rather than having a permanent change to the save function.

Comment: No, not possible.  http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E0000000kAr7IAE

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no such function. Save a Copy is the only possibility for now. Hopefully, ESRI will work on it.